# JavaScript type for "streaming" array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, streaming, es6-promise

I have an array of objects which I get from an async function and I'd like to "open a channel" and "stream" the received objects. How can I realize this concept.
Probably I'd like to append objects to the "stream" from different places in my code

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve? If you get an array of objects, you already have them all available, so why would you "stream" them somewhere rather than directly passing on the array?

Comment: I am querying transactions from blockchain by block - I would like to append data to the stream each time I get a result for the next block

Comment: nodejs' streams can operate in object mode.

Comment: Use a stream library like RxJS, Most.js or xstream

Answer (score 1):

So you want to run an async function periodically or based on some input array, make an asynchronous call and get push the items of the returned array as a stream.

As @fathyb proposed that would be easiest to achieve using a stream library, the example below is with [scramjet](https://scramjet.eu):

```
const {DataStream} = require("scramjet");

const blocks = require("input-array.json"); // the array of inputs

const myStream = DataStream.fromArray(blocks)                
                                            // create a stream from your input array
    .setOptions({maxParallel: 1})           // make sure you're running 1 call at a time
    .map(async (block) => yourAsyncFunction(block)) 
                                            // get the data asynchronously 
                                            // and return a stream of arrays
    .flatten()                              // last - turn your arrays into a stream of
                                            // contents
```

This should be what you're after in a couple simple lines. :)

Comment: currently I implemented the thing with events, may be will get a try to this solution as well

Comment: The problem with events is that you will have to control the flow manually - pausing and resuming the stream - as it won't wait until next item is ready.

Scramjet does all that for you and all you need to do is simply return a promise - it'll use it to keep track of concurrency and flow control.